# Alienware or Macbook Pro? Which one is worth it?

Tags: laptop, gaming, video-editing

I'm planning to buy a new laptop since my current PC(Lenovo U430) is kind of slow when it comes to gaming and video editing. My current budget is $1,000 to $1,500, after researching, I'm planning to buy one of these brands: Alienware 13 inch(latest model) or Macbook Pro 13 inch(with retina display) only.**Question: Which brand or model should I be buying that is compatible and worth it for a little gaming, graphic design, video editing(no lagging while editing or checking the video preview in After Effects or Premiere Pro) with my current budget? Aliewanre or Macbook?**

Here's the link to Alienware 13 inch list of models: http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/alienware-13-laptop?~ck=mn

Here's the link to Macbook Pro 13 inch list of models: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=macbook+pro+retina+display+13&_dyncharset=UTF-8&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&af=true&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys

Comment your answer with the link or the brand and specs of the model.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Voting to close as this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @NZKshatriya it is not opinion based, it's more of a lack of knowledge. Macbooks were never designed for gaming, but for his video editing it might be just enough. He would still be better off with the Alienware if he plays games, since it has a dedicated GPU

Comment: Then his heading question needs to reflect better his actual question.  Asking which one is worth it is very opinionated.  Personally, I don't think either one is really "worth it" but that's my opinion.

Comment: What games will you be playing? Keep in mind that OSX does not support the same games that you can play on Windows, so do your research before purchasing. Can you list out a complete list of programs that you will be running? I see After Effects and Premiere, but are there any others? When you browse the internet, about how many tabs do you have open at once?

Comment: I am a mac book pro owner (2011, 17") myself.  Mac OS has many advantages, security foremost, but, right now, I would **not** opt for a Mac as far as hardware goes.  Everything is totally locked down on newer models - RAM, HD/SDD, everything.  They are totally non-upgradeable, and quite possibly hard to service as well.  This isn't the case with my older Mac.  And the $$$ ding to go up from say a 256GB to 512GB SSD at purchase is massive, much more than you would expect from the aftermarket parts prices.  As a Mac owner, I hate to say this, but Apple is really fleecing nowadays.

Comment: For most things Macs will perform on par with PCs, except gaming. My experience is that they perform worse in games even with same hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For overall "OUT OF THE BOX" compatibility you are going to be better off going with a PC.

Performance wise comparing the two you will get the following benefits of the base model Alienware laptop over the MacBook.

1) Faster Processor

2) Larger HDD

3) Much better video card (the MacBook only has Intel Iris integrated video)

4) $100 Less expensive with reward card rebate

All of these items are using the base model Alienware laptop that you provided a link for.  With the extra money you could add some more power or featurs or move up the next model.

Comment: The alienware 13 laptops have CUDA capable GPUs. CUDA will help with render times in Adobe AE and PR.

Comment: I 3rd this answer for the simple fact that PC typically run cooler and collect less dust. Macs are NOT dust friendly and difficult to clean. Graphic intense type things will cook a Mac GPU pretty quick.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. Thanks for the tip 0-60fps and @DanV yeah I got friends who go either a burned ram or video cards. Jeff, thank you very informative !